# What is this mysterious macro plus sign in stdint.h?

Tags: c, macros, stdint

Please see my code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
unsigned char s = 0xffU;
char ch = 0xff;
int val = 78;
((int8_t) + (78)); /*what does this mean*/

INT8_C(val);    /*equivalent to above*/

signed char + 78; /*not allowed*/

return 0;
}
```

I find that the macro definition in `<stdint.h>` is:

```
#define INT8_C(val) ((int8_t) + (val))
```

What is the meaning or significance of this plus sign?

Comment: It should be noted that this definition of `INT8_C` is wrong: 7.18.4 paragraph 3: "Each invocation of one of these macros (NOTE: referring to `INTN_C`) shall expand to an integer constant expression **suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives.**" That cast won't work in a preprocessor directive, since types (and hence casts) don't exist during preprocessing. What compiler/platform are you using? You should consider filing a bug report about this.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: It was valid in C99; it became invalid in Technical Corrigendum 1, which is incorporated into N1256.  This was in response to [DR #209](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_209.htm).

Comment: @KeithThompson - Ah. I have a copy of TC2, and until pretty recently wasn't really aware of the Technical Corrigenda.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The snippet:

```
((int8_t) + (78));
```

is an *expression,* one that takes the value `78`, applies the unary `+`, then casts that to an `int8_t` type, before throwing it away. It is no real different to the legal expressions:

```
42;
a + 1;
```

which also evaluate the expressions then throw away the result (though these will possibly be optimised out of existence if the compiler can tell that there are no side effects).

These "naked" expressions are perfectly valid in C and generally useful only when they have side effects, such as with `i++`, which calculates `i` and throws it away with the side effect being that it increments the value.

The way you *should* be using that macro is more along the lines of:

```
int8_t varname = INT8_C (somevalue);
```

The reason for the seemingly redundant unary `+` operator can be found in the standard. Quoting C99 `6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators /1`:

> The operand of the unary + or - operator shall have arithmetic type;

And, in `6.2.5 Types, /18`:

> Integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types.

In other words, the unary `+` prevents you from using all the other data types in the macro, such as pointers, complex numbers or structures.

And, finally, the reason your:

```
signed char + 78;
```

snippet doesn't work is because it's not the same thing. This one is starting to declare a variable of type `signed char` but chokes when it gets to the `+` since that's not a legal variable name. To make it equivalent to your working snippet, you would use:

```
(signed char) + 78;
```

which is the casting of the value `+78` to type `signed char`.

And, as per C99 `7.8.14 Macros for integer constants /2`, you should also be careful with using non-constants in those macros, they're not guaranteed to work:

> The argument in any instance of these macros shall be an unsuffixed integer constant (as
>    defined in 6.4.4.1) with a value that does not exceed the limits for the corresponding type.

`6.4.4.1` simply specifies the various integer formats (decimal/octal/hex) with the various suffixes (`U`, `UL`, `ULL`, `L`, `LL` and the lower-case equivalents, depending on the type). The bottom line is that they have to be *constants* rather than variables.

For example, `glibc` has:

```
# define INT8_C(c)      c
# define INT16_C(c)     c
# define INT32_C(c)     c
# if __WORDSIZE == 64
#  define INT64_C(c)    c ## L
# else
#  define INT64_C(c)    c ## LL
# endif
```

which will allow your `INT8_C` macro to work fine but the text `INT64_C(val)` would be pre-processed into either `valL` or `valLL`, neither of which you would want.

Comment: Actually, the definition the OP gives for `INT8_C` violates the standard, by my reading. 7.18.4 paragraph 3: "Each invocation of one of these macros shall expand to an integer constant expression **suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives.**" The original definition of `INT8_C` can't be used in an `#if` directive, and hence is incorrect.

Comment: @Chris: The + makes it valid in preprocessing directives. `int8_t` expands to 0, and `(0)+(val)` is simply `val`.

Comment: How does `int8_t` expand to 0? I thought it was a typedef? o_O

Comment: @Karl - any identifier that the preprocessor doesn't know about is evaluated as 0 by the preprocessor in an expression.

Comment: ahh, I see, it doesn't care that there is a typedef for `int8_t` somewhere else because typedefs are outside of its domain of understanding (and interpreted later in the process anyway).

Answer (score 18):

Seems everyone has missed the point of the unary plus operator here, which is to make the result valid in `#if` preprocessor directives. Given:

```
#define INT8_C(val) ((int8_t) + (val))
```

the directives:

```
#define FOO 1
#if FOO == INT8_C(1)
```

expand as:

```
#if 1 == ((0) + (1))
```

and thus work as expected. This is due to the fact that any un`#define`d symbol in an `#if` directive expands to `0`.

Without the unary plus (which becomes a binary plus in `#if` directives), the expression would not be valid in `#if` directives.

Comment: That's really bizarre, and unfortunately works. Does this count as obfuscated C code? I think having `+` be a unary operator in one situation and a binary operator in another, relying on `(int8_t)` being interpreted as a cast or as an undefined symbol, is bordering on obfuscation...

Comment: That's simultaneously beautiful and ugly.

Answer (score 10):

It's a unary `+` operator.  It yields the value of its operand, but it can be applied only to arithmetic types.  The purpose here is to prevent the use of `INT8_C` on an expression of pointer type.

But your statement expression

```
INT8_C(val);
```

has undefined behavior.  The argument to `INT8_C()` is required to be "an unsufﬁxed integer constant ... with a value that does not exceed the limits for the corresponding type" ([N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 7.18.4).  The intent of these macros is to let you write something like `INT64_C(42)` and have it expand to `42L` if `int64_t` is `long`, or to `42LL` if `int64_t` is `long long, and so forth.

But writing either

```
((int8_t) + (78));
```

or

```
((int8_t) + (val));
```

in your own code is perfectly legal.

**EDIT**:

The definition for `INT8_C()` in the question:

```
#define INT8_C(val) ((int8_t) + (val))
```

is valid in C99, but is non-conforming according to the later N1256 draft, as a result of a change in one of the Technical Corrigenda.

The original C99 standard, section 7.18.4.1p2, says:

> The macro **INT***N***_C**(*value*) shall expand to a signed integer constant with
>   the speciﬁed value and type **int_least***N***_t**.

N1256 changed this to (paragraph 3):

> Each invocation of one of these macros shall expand to an integer
>   constant expression suitable for use in **#if** preprocessing directives.
>   The type of the expression shall have the same type as would an
>   expression of the corresponding type converted according to the
>   integer promotions. The value of the expression shall be that of the
>   argument.

The change was made in response to [Defect Report #209](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_209.htm).

**EDIT2**: But see R..'s answer; it's actually valid in N1256, for quite obscure reasons.

Comment: Not only is the OP's code wrong, the OP's copy of `stdint.h` is wrong (if that's really his definition of `INT8_C`).

Comment: It violates 7.18.4 paragraph 3. See my answer below so I don't keep spamming that paragraph all over the place.

Comment: Better read @R..'s answer, that one give the solution to the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

That's a unary plus.

There are only two things it *could* be doing.

1. It applies what are know as the *usual arithmetic conversions* to the operand. This establishes a *common real type* for a result. I can't think of any reason to force this if the result is about to be cast into something specific.
2. It restricts the operand to types for which arithmetic operators are defined. This seems like the more likely reason.